Forces on an elliptical current-carrying Loop
Consider a current-carrying elliptical 1-turn coil as shown in the picture below:

Is it true that due to forces from the current, the elliptical shape of the coil will tend to become circular?

parallel currents attract and antiparallel currents repel each other so an elliptic loop current should be getting more "circularized" under its own current.

Thanks for Reply . You are sure or you suppose. Can you verify the answer with link? Thank you for.

Max Planck: "Introduction to theoretical physics - Theory of electricity and magnetism", Macmillan 1932, page 167 "The ponderomotive forces between the conductors carrying the currents always act in a direction such that the number of lines of induction becomes as large as possible ; this may be achieved by translation or rotation. Hence currents that are parallel and in the same direction attract each other whereas parallel and opposite currents repel each other or seek to turn themselves so that they run in the same direction."

I'd say yes.
Imagine the ellipse is deformed until it's a rectangle with a longer length $L'$, and a constant small spacing $W'$. This now looks like two wires close to each other, with opposite currents, which will repel.
Therefore, a current in a wire loop will repel across itself, for the entire loop, and this force, if sufficient for the wire size, would deform the wire ellipse into a circle.

Thanks for answear. Other answers are welcome too. If you can post links will be great. Thank you.

You're welcome. Sorry, I answered without any links about your question directly, but wires with opposite currents repelling has been answered separately: https://byjus.com/question-answer/two-free-parallel-wires-carrying-currents-in-opposite-directions-attract-each-other-do-not-affect-1/

A simple way to see this is to consider a two solenoids. If they are placed over one another, with the currents going in the same direction, you'll get magnetic N/S between them and they will attract each other. If you flip one over so the currents are going the opposite directions, you'll get N/N (or S/S depending on which one you flip) and they'll repel each other.
